How to save n-gram output
A hopefully simple question. How can I save the ngram output from the following code?
\\
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.2

data(data_corpus_inaugural)

toks <- data_corpus_inaugural %>% 
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE,
         remove_symbol = TRUE, 
         padding = TRUE) %>% 
  tokens_tolower()

tokens <- dfm(toks)

toks <- my_corpus %>% 
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE,
         remove_symbol = TRUE, 
         padding = TRUE)


toks_ngram <- tokens_ngrams(toks, n = 2:7)

\\

You can save it as rds object
saveRDS(toks_ngram, "toks_ngram.rds")


Thanks Sadettin. I can see I should have been clearer, I want to be able to save the output so I can read it as a text file or preferably a csv file.  Because of the file size, when I try to read the rds file, it will only display the first 29 documents.

Your toks_ngram object is a token format, you should make a dfm out it and then you can get frequency by textstat_frequency() Later you may save it as csv. Here is the code. data<- dfm(toks_ngram) %>% textstat_frequency() nad then write.csv(data, "data.csv")

Many thanks Sadetin,  this may be as good as I can get.  The original output was:                               : 11_2-7-98.txt :
[1] "It_has"           "has_been"         "been_very"        "very_interesting" "interesting_to"   "to_sit"
[7] "sit_here"         "here_and"         "and_listen"       "listen_to"        "to_all"           "all_the"
#21_3-6-98.txt :
[1] "Today_in"       "in_the"         "the_House"      "House_I"        "I_asked"        "asked_the"      "the_Prime"
[8] "Prime_Minister" "Mr_Howard"      "when_he"        "he_was"         "was_going"

The original output had the advantage of identifying the document the term occurred in.  I may just have to supplement the saved output with KWIC analyses.
